# How do I store the value of a shell script executed in putty to a variable in Jenkins groovy pipeline?

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am calling a .sh from Jenkins groovy pipeline in on of its stage. The .sh is getting executed on putty (Jenkins slave). I want to store the output of that .sh file to a variable which can be used inside the Jenkins groovy pipeline.

I have tried the below code, but it hasn't helped. That's why I am executing the shell on putty and then storing  the variable:

```
result = sh (

script: 'shell code',
returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "Output: ${result}"
```

The variable result should get the value of shell script to be used further in the groovy pipeline

Comment: The sh file execution log also display in job's console output, please show the logs of the sh file.  And show the stage code where above code inside.

Comment: stage { …  ./abc.sh …} This abc.sh returns the line present between two patterns using awk and grep . I want to store the output of abc.sh (which is a string) to a variable in Jenkins groovy pipeline so as to use the variable further. I am executing the shell in putty on one of the configured Jenkins slaves.